# jQuery Tooltip - close tooltip dialog without hiding the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

I trying to close any open jQuery tooltips which are open.

1. When I use `$(".selector").tooltip("close")`, nothing happens.
2. When I use `$(".selector").tooltip().remove()`, it removes the tooltip but the textbox also disappears.

Is there a way to just remove only the tooltip dialog?

**NOTE:** If a user select the text in a textbox and drags the mouse, the tooltip window remains open, that is why I am trying to force-close it.

Answer (score 0):

My believe is that you are removing the element. I will suggest to hide the `tooltip` with its option `hide`.

```
$('#element').tooltip('hide');
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-hide

Can also use the option close if you actually wants to hide/close the tooltip instead of removing it.

```
$('#element').tooltip( "close" );
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-close